# Вывод адреса указателя

Tags: c++, указатели, char

начал изучать C++, тема указатели.

Вывод следующий

```
pcName1[0] - 0x4f &pcName1[0] - 0x55d7b3e50008
pcName1[1] - 0x6e &pcName1[1] - 0x55d7b3e50009
pcName1[2] - 0x65 &pcName1[2] - 0x55d7b3e5000a
pcName1[3] - 0x2c &pcName1[3] - 0x55d7b3e5000b
pcName1[4] - 0x20 &pcName1[4] - 0x55d7b3e5000c
pcName1[5] - 0x74 &pcName1[5] - 0x55d7b3e5000d
pcName1[6] - 0x77 &pcName1[6] - 0x55d7b3e5000e
pcName1[7] - 0x6f &pcName1[7] - 0x55d7b3e5000f
```

`&pcName1[0] - 0x55d7b3e50008`  - это адрес в котором хранится первый символ
`pcName1[0] - 0x4f` - не могу понять что это за адрес?

```
char* pcName1 = "One, two";

    int i{0};
    while(pcName1[i]){
      printf("pcName1[%d] - %p ", i, pcName1[i]);
      printf("&pcName1[%d] - %p ", i, &pcName1[i]);
      printf("\n");
      i++;
    }
```

Comment: это не адрес. это вы распечатали код символа в строке.

Comment: Это не адрес, а запись в шестнадцатеричном виде символа, хранящегося в  `pcName1[0]`. См. в этой [таблице](https://www.asciitable.com/) код символа `O`. Просто вы запросили его вывод *как значения указателя*, т.е. в шестнадцатеричном виде...

Comment: @Harry понял, спасибо большое за разъяснение

Comment: @pavel понял, спасибо большое за разъяснение

Answer (score 1):

Это вообще не адрес. Попытка передать `char` (т.е. `pcName1[i]`) в `"%p"` (который ожидает указатель) вызывает неопределенное поведение.

Видимо, в вашем случае ASCII-код i-ого символа напечатался как шестнадцатеричное число.

Тут должно было выскочить предупреждение, если не выскочило - компилятор плохо настроен.

`char* pcName1 = "One, two";` - не должно компилироваться в C++11 и новее, нужен `const` слева. Если у вас компилируется, то компилятор слишком старый, и/или не настроен использовать свежую версию C++.

Comment: Понял спасибо большое за разъяснение, получается поймал undefined behavior =) Компилятор выдает предупреждение. main.cpp:7:25: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]. Пользуюсь g++ (Debian 13.1.0-6) 13.1.0

Comment: @stas-z20 Вот нормальный набор флагов `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -std=c++23`. Тогда на первое будет ворнинг, а на второе - ошибка.

Comment: спасибо, буду применять